# How to disable DNS cache on macOS?

Tags: dns

I'm using my mac for software development and the app I'm working on creates new domains and use them after a few minutes. The problem is these domains not resolved in a few minutes, so I have to clean DNS cache by running:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache; sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

I wonder, is there a way to completely disable DNS cache for some time (while I'm developing)?